# Apache JMeter Load Simulation in Intervals

Tags: jmeter, simulation, intervals, schedule

I'm currently using Apache JMeter to run load tests on the REST interfaces of my backend application. The test plan currently uses two thread groups and runs those in loops. Both thread groups are sending particular REST requests at a certain throughput using a constant throughput timer. The first thread group randomly picks one of several different REST requests, while the other uses one fixed REST request.

With this setup, I'm able to fire load to my application at a constant throughput. Now, I would like to simulate that over a day/night load profile, given that from e.g. 8:00 am to 5:00 pm the load is at a certain constant throughput, while in the rest of the time (the night), the load drops to a lower throughput or even stops entirely. Then at 8:00 am the next morning, it rises again.

Do you guys know if such a load profile can be simulated using Apache JMeter? Do you also know, which constructs could be used to setup something like that?

Thanks for any hint.

Regards
Timo

Comment: try JMeter plugin jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group

Answer (score 0):

You can consider switching to [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) which seems to be exactly what you're looking for. See [Special Property Processing](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing) chapter for the "load profiles" bit.

You can get Throughput Shaping Timer element via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: Throughput Shaping Timer Plugins Manager]